# MySqlDataReader error when running the method twice

Tags: c#, mysqldatareader

I have this code. When I execute this once, I am able to get the correct list. But when I run this method again, the reader has no data. I was thinking did I forget to close some connection before calling it again, thus leading to the null result

```
 public IEnumerable<List<string>> retreiveList()
 {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM table1;";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            List<string> toReturn=new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)                
                toReturn.Add(reader[i].ToString());
            yield return toReturn;
        }
        reader.Close();         
    }
```

Comment: I don't quite get, what it is, you are trying to do here? Why the "yield return"? Do you want to implement sone Enumerator?

Comment: Because it a list<list<string>> so I using IEnumerable

Comment: That's all fine, you actually can return an IEnumerable without having to use yield return, you know that right?